# A loop that only adds non duplicate values to a a list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

EDIT: OP here, its answered. Can't accept my own answer for 2 days? Dunno I'm a stack noob. Thanks to people that helped.

I want to have a loop that generates a random coordinate and adds it to a list only if that coordinate does not already exist in the list.

And just keeps looping until the correct number of coordinates are in the list.

```
    while (spawnPositions.Count < myPlayer.myPlayerUnits.Count)
    {
        Debug.Log("While");
        int[,] rnd = new int[UnityEngine.Random.Range(minX, maxX), UnityEngine.Random.Range(minZ, maxZ)];

        if (spawnPositions.Contains(rnd) == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("SpawnPos Added!");
            spawnPositions.Add(rnd);
        }
    }
```

Problem is the if statement is always true. Console output shows the loop loops X amount of times and the if statement is also true X amount of times.

Is this just not possible to do in while-loop. Or am i doing something wrong? Thanks!

EDIT: Oh and to be clear yes duplicates are added. I'm trying to generate 5 unique coordinates on a 3x3 area and there is almost always duplicates!

Comment: please create a [MCVE]

Comment: maybe you don't have duplicates... Have you checked that there are duplicates added to the list?

Comment: @bolov Yeah, I've edited the post. Thanks!

Comment: You may need to perform a `spawnPositions.Clear()` first before adding new values. Also, `UnityEngine.Random.Range` accepts and returns floats, not ints, so you're specifying the wrong value types. (You also don't show us how your min variables are defined.)

Comment: @Stahhl still no [MCVE]. We are left to guess what `spawnPositions` type is and so on. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: The problem is that .Contains() in this case is looking for references and they are always unique. It does not look for the values in the 2D array which you are looking for. You need to specify the comparison yourself. For example: `if(spawnPositions.All(p => !YourEqualityCompare(p, rnd)))`.

Comment: You know that `int[,] rnd = new int[UnityEngine.Random.Range(minX, maxX), UnityEngine.Random.Range(minZ, maxZ)];` creates a new multidimensional array `int` with the random sizes but with only default values `0`, right? Why not using `Vector2` for the positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: OP here, its answered. Can't accept my own answer for 2 days? Dunno I'm a stack noob. Thanks to people that helped.

I fixed it, its not pretty but it works. An array of booleans to keep track if the value have been used already. And not actaully adding/removing values from the list from within the while-loop (had a few infinite-loops trying out things :S).

```
    bool[,] tileOccupied = new bool[maxX, maxZ];

    for (int i = 0; i < myPlayer.myPlayerUnits.Count; i++)
    {
        int tileValue = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, myPlayer.mySpawnArea.Count);
        int[,] spawnTile = myPlayer.mySpawnArea[tileValue];

        if (tileOccupied[spawnTile.GetLength(0), spawnTile.GetLength(1)] == true)
        {
            do
            {
                tileValue = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, myPlayer.mySpawnArea.Count - 1);
                spawnTile = myPlayer.mySpawnArea[tileValue];
            } while (tileOccupied[spawnTile.GetLength(0), spawnTile.GetLength(1)] == true);
        }
        tileOccupied[spawnTile.GetLength(0), spawnTile.GetLength(1)] = true;
        spawnPositions.Add(spawnTile);
    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense to me at all. There's a very easy way to make a distinct set of random values, but without a [mcve] it's hard to give you an answer that is relevant to you. Please make one so that we can help.

Comment: It works and the code is ran once so it doesn't matter that it´s unoptimized. But thanks anyway.

Comment: It does matter very much. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a library of quality questions and answers **for the community at large**. It's only a secondary purpose that the person asking the question actually gets an answer. In this case your code appear to be correct to me, so it's not a good quality question and answer. I simply am asking you to get it up to standard.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you want to compare the content of multidimensional arrays or maybe only their dimensions. But the .Contains() method looks for the reference equality and this is always unique because you are calling "new".
I defined a extension method for it.

```
    public static bool IsContentEqualTo(this int[,] array1, int[,] array2)
    {
        if (array1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array1), "Array cannot be null");
        if (array2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array2), "Array cannot be null");
        if (array1.GetLowerBound(0) != array2.GetLowerBound(0)) return false;
        if (array1.GetUpperBound(0) != array2.GetUpperBound(0)) return false;
        if (array1.GetLowerBound(1) != array2.GetLowerBound(1)) return false;
        if (array1.GetUpperBound(1) != array2.GetUpperBound(1)) return false;

        var xMin = array1.GetLowerBound(0);
        var xMax = array1.GetUpperBound(0);
        var yMin = array1.GetLowerBound(1);
        var yMax = array1.GetUpperBound(1);
        for (var x = xMin; x <= xMax; x++)
            for (var y = yMin; y <= yMax; y++)
            {
                if (array1[x, y] != array2[x, y]) return false;
            }

        return true;
    }
```

And you can call it like that.

```
    if (!spawnPositions.Any(array => array.IsContentEqualTo(rnd)))
    {
        Debug.Log("SpawnPos Added!");
        spawnPositions.Add(rnd);
    }
```